# How to pass property as a parameter in order to use the same function to modify different properties

Tags: c#, properties, parameters, linq-to-objects

I've found similar questions asked before but the answers I've seen have been specific to the example given by the person or workarounds for that person's example, not a general solution.

I'd like to pass a class' property to a function to do an operation on that property. The example I'm going to use is incrementing a value, but I have more complicated scenarios so I'm looking for a general solution, not an answer for specifically incrementing.

How I used to do it is I'd either have multiple functions `IncrementPassengerCount`, `IncrementDistanceTravelled`, `IncrementPlaneAge`, but that's unweildly and horrible.

I'd like one general function that I can call using something like this pseudocode:

```
Increment(myPlane, myPlane.DistanceTravelled);
Increment(myPlane, myPlane.PlaneAge);

//where

public void Increment(Airplane myPlane, Property propToIncrement)
{
     myPlane.propToIncrement++; //or do whatever like I now have myPlane.DistanceTravelled
}
```

I've tried this:

```
Increment(myPlane, x => x.DistanceTravelled);

//where

public void Increment(Airplane myPlane, Func<Log, IComparable> property)
{
     property(myPlane)++;
}
```

But this causes a

> Operator '++' cannot be applied to operand of type 'System.IComparable'

Is there a way to do what I'm imagining or am I looking at it wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't pass properties by reference, at most you will be able to increase the local variable holding the argument passed to the method. Try passing a delegate you can call that will increase the correct property instead.

Comment: Are you doing anything else in the method? At the moment even if it *could* be done it would seem rather more complicated than just `myPlane.DistanceTravelled++`

Comment: Bummer. Okay, thanks. I'll leave the question open just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Is is possible, though convoluted and probably a sign that you should perhaps do it a different way, but here it is. (I would recommend as Jon Skeet mentioned, to just use the ++ operator instead of invoking the Increment method. In addition to the method I included two classes that will allow you to test the code in a console app. There would need to be plenty of error checking. I have a few null checks, but there may be more locations it is needed. If you have overloaded the ++ operator, it works for those types too, but any errors cannot be anticipated.

```
public static void Increment(this object o, string propertyName)  
    {
        var property = o.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);

        if (property == null)
            return;

        var val = property.GetValue(o, null);
        var op_Inc = o.GetType().GetMethod("op_Increment");

        if(op_Inc != null)
        {
            var val2 = op_Inc.Invoke(val, null);
            property.SetValue(o,val2);
        }

        switch (Type.GetTypeCode(property.PropertyType))
        {

            case TypeCode.UInt16:
            {
                var x = (UInt16)val;
                x++;
                property.SetValue(o, x);
            }
                break;
            case TypeCode.UInt32:
                {
                    var x = (UInt32)val;
                    x++;
                    property.SetValue(o, x);
                }
                break;
            case TypeCode.UInt64:
                {
                    var x = (UInt64)val;
                    x++;
                    property.SetValue(o, x);
                }
                break;
            case TypeCode.Int16:
                {
                    var x = (Int16)val;
                    x++;
                    property.SetValue(o, x);
                }
                break;
            case TypeCode.Int32:
                {
                    var x = (Int32)val;
                    x++;
                    property.SetValue(o, x);
                }
                break;
            case TypeCode.Int64:
                {
                    var x = (Int64)val;
                    x++;
                    property.SetValue(o, x);
                }
                break;
            case TypeCode.Decimal:
                {
                    var x = (Decimal)val;
                    x++;
                    property.SetValue(o, x);
                }
                break;
            case TypeCode.Double:
                {
                    var x = (Double)val;
                    x++;
                    property.SetValue(o, x);
                }
                break;
            case TypeCode.Single:
                {
                    var x = (Single)val;
                    x++;
                    property.SetValue(o, x);
                }
                break;

        }


    }
}

public class Example
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        var plane = new Plane(){DistanceTravelled = 0, PlaneAge = 0};
        Console.WriteLine("Before invoking increment: dist = {0}, age = {1}", plane.DistanceTravelled, plane.PlaneAge);
        plane.Increment("DistanceTravelled");
        plane.Increment("PlaneAge");
        Console.WriteLine("After invoking increment: dist = {0}, age = {1}", plane.DistanceTravelled, plane.PlaneAge);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }


}

public class Plane
{
    public int DistanceTravelled { get; set; }

    public int PlaneAge { get; set; }

}
```